Designing a Tournament Schedule With Several Caveats
I am scheduling a bowls tournament containing 14 teams split into 2 groups of 7.
Each team will play every other team in their group so a total of 6 matches.
In this form of bowls, we play on specific mats and no team can play consecutively on the same mat.
I have 6 mats available. Mats do not have to be assigned to either of the specific groups- the key is simply that I do not want a team playing on the same mat consecutively. It would be ideal if each team had one playing session rest- so one team from each of the two groups is off/ not playing during each session.
I hope that this makes sense but if not please do ask and I will attempt to provide any additional context needed. I am looking for a schedule that will enable:
-A team to play the 6 other teams in its group without playing on the same mat consecutively.
-Each team to have 1 x playing session off.
Many thanks in advance.

Just split the $6$ mats into two groups of $3$ and alternate team group plays on both mat groups. For example, suppose the mats are split into
$$\text{Mat group 1}: \text{ Mat }1,\text{ Mat }2,\text{ Mat }3$$
$$\text{Mat group 2}: \text{ Mat }4,\text{ Mat }5,\text{ Mat }6$$
and the teams are Group A and Group B. Then during the first round, Group A starts on mat group $1$ and Group B is on mat group $2$. During the second round, Group A is on mat group $2$ and Group B is on mat group $1$. A possible match order within Group A (and similarly for Group B) is below
$$\text{Round 1}:12,34,56,7R$$
$$\text{Round 2}:17,36,45,2R$$
$$\text{Round 3}:46,27,35,1R$$
$$\text{Round 4}:16,57,24,3R$$
$$\text{Round 5}:13,47,25,6R$$
$$\text{Round 6}:26,15,37,4R$$
$$\text{Round 7}:14,23,67,5R$$
where $R$ is obviously the team resting.

Much simpler than my answer ^^'

R is equivalent to an $8$th team who failed to attend, so giving their opponents a rest. If you had an even number of teams in each group instead of $7$ then this would not work so well as you would have to give them an even number of rests (on average) such as $0$ or $2$.
